# Java - Specify fields to return in REST

Tags: java, json, rest, field, jax-rs

I am implementing REST based services in Java, but I don't want to return the full entity in JSON for each GET call.

What i have right now is this

```
@GET
@Path("movie/{id}")
@Produces({"application/json"})
public Movie find(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
    return getEntityManager().find(Movie.class, id);
}
```

With the above code I can get a full JSON representation of the movie specified by id however I would like to do something like this:

```
GET>http://mydomain.com/movie/id=1?fields=title,year
```

Here, I pass the `id` of the movie and the fields that I'd like returned in a JSON formatted response.

Is there a simple way to do this or an existing library that alraedy does this?

**EDIT:**
Yes A.J i ended up finding the same example but i cant make it work

In that example they have a file with all the configurations necessary

```
  @ApplicationPath("/")
  public class SelectableEntityFilteringApplication extends ResourceConfig {

  public SelectableEntityFilteringApplication() {
      // Register all resources present under the package.
      packages("org.glassfish.jersey.examples.entityfiltering.selectable");

      // Register entity-filtering selectable feature.
      register(SelectableEntityFilteringFeature.class);

      // Configure MOXy Json provider.
      register(new MoxyJsonConfig().setFormattedOutput(true).resolver());

      property(SelectableEntityFilteringFeature.QUERY_PARAM_NAME, "select");

  }
```

}

but since im using J2EE the file generated by my IDE was this

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    //register(SelectableEntityFilteringFeature.class);
    Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
    addRestResourceClasses(resources);
    return resources;
}
```

and i cant register the class, do i really have to extend ResourceConfig? Doesnt seem to be compatible with javax.ws.rs.core.Application

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to use a json library and build the response yourself; if you return a json object or string you will have full control over the output.

Comment: True, but i will have to build a lot of REST services, also i have a lot of entitys so if i do that for all of them it will consume a lot of time while doing something that i dont really have to think, just write. What for me is really anoying :) But ye as last resort thats an option

Comment: Hmm, you basically want the reverse of URI templates here... With a URI template you could do `http://mydomain.com/movie/id={id}?fields={fields}` where `id` is a scalar and `fields` an array, but while URI templates define _expansion_, they don't define parsing... (see RFC 6570 for more details)

Comment: is Jersey used on server side?

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using Jersey, you probably can use what its filtering facility.
following is a link for for the relevant chapter in docs: [Entity Filtering](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/entity-filtering.html)

section [19.5](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/entity-filtering.html#ef.selectable.annotations) looks to be matching your requirement.

Note: I did not use this before (the feature of filtering, I did use Jersey).
I found it using google. So I can't provide example on how to make it work.

EDIT: an example: https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/entity-filtering-selectable

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be what i want, i dont understant how it works and i cant seem to find an example on google, but i will try it and report back.

Comment: there seems not to be many examples. I was able to locate only one. check the edit in the post.

Comment: yes, i managed to find that too, check my edit, I am having problems with that example